# Program for saving windows configuration after reinstalling?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

Is there some program that saves Windows configuration as you have before reinstalling the same operating system?

For example, I want a program which scans all (or some main) configuration's in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the "Windows Easy Transfer" to move data and configuration to your new machine.  Also, if you are re-installing on the same machine, the windows 7 install should ask you if you want to retain your data and settings.

Comment: thnx man that is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Windows also offers an informational tutorial video about *Windows Easy Transfer* here if you want to check it out:

> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

Comment: we refrain from signatures of any kind here. Thanks for your cooperation!

Comment: also, your answer is a close duplicate of @Brian's answer; please do not repost solutions.